# moving multiple objects on a Tkinter canvas simultaneously

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter Canvas with a lot of pictures on it, Is there any way to move them all easily? I know about 'canvas.move' but, its very repetitive and clustered when using it for many objects. Is there a way to move all objects on a canvas at the same time or, perhaps, combine all the pictures into a single object(using python)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the constant `ALL` to the move method:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 60, 60)
canvas.create_rectangle(70, 70, 120, 120)
canvas.pack()
canvas.move(ALL, 50, 50)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, This was exactly what I was looking for. I am pretty new to Python so help like this is really great.